# OpenSSH upgrade from 7.6 to 8.3

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openssh

I need to upgrade OpenSSH from 7.6 to 8.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-99-generic x86_64)
I tried to do like below

```
installing OpenSSL

$ sudo apt remove libssl-dev
$ sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
$ tar -zxvf openssl-3.0.0-alpha3.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-3.0.0-alpha3
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

**then trying to install the latest version of OpenSSH**

```
$ tar -zxvf openssh-8.3p1.tar.gz
$ cd openssh-8.3p1
$ ./configure --without-openssl-header-check (due to errors with headers)
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1# make
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/openssh-8.3p1/openbsd-compat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/openssh-8.3p1/openbsd-compat'
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1# 
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1# sudo make install
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/openssh-8.3p1/openbsd-compat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/openssh-8.3p1/openbsd-compat'
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man5
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man8
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/libexec
/bin/mkdir -p -m 0755 /var/empty
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s scp /usr/local/bin/scp
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-add /usr/local/bin/ssh-add
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-agent /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keygen /usr/local/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keyscan /usr/local/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd /usr/local/sbin/sshd
/usr/bin/install -c -m 4711 -s ssh-keysign /usr/local/libexec/ssh-keysign
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-pkcs11-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-sk-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-sk-helper
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp-server /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 scp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/scp.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-add.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 moduli.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/moduli.5
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sshd.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/sftp.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp-server.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-sk-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-sk-helper.8
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/etc
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1#
```

**but if I check OpenSSH version, it returns the same version as it was before**

```
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:~/openssh-8.3p1#
```

**Can any body help with this issue?**
everything is done remotely, because it is VM

Answer (score 1):

You installed ssh to `/usr/local/bin/ssh`. Default is `/usr/bin/ssh`.

You can either configure it to install to /usr/bin or you can use /usr/local/bin/ssh.

`/usr/local/bin/ssh -V` should show the new version.

You can check all ssh in your path in bash with `type -pa ssh`.

Comment: hi `root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# /usr/local/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
root@vkc-cms-mongo-pr:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# ` but how this can be applicable for OS?

Comment: how can I install ssh 8.3 to /usr/bin/ssh so that by command `ssh -V` to get correct result and using ssh 8.3?

Comment: e.g. by cooying it from /usr/local/bin/ to /usr/bin/ or specify the proper option with configure. I think you can call configure --help or you can set your path variable so that /usr/local/bin/ comes before /usr/bin/ or you can create an bash alias or function for ssh that calls /usr/local/bin/ssh or ...